# Unknown command error while restoring database from MySQL dump

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.1.36. While importing form a MySQL dump
I am getting the following error. The 'max_allowed_packet' size is set to 100M in the my.cnf.

ERROR at line 1647: Unknown command '\''.

Can you please tell me what could be the issue ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Comment: Could we see, say, lines 1640-1655 of the dump file?

Comment: the data contains some binary data and it will be large enough to post here. The problem is it works sometimes and sometimes it throws the above error. How you want me to proceed ?

Comment: Are you saying that you can, starting each time from a clean and empty db, repeatedly import the same dump file, and sometimes it errors and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: We are taking dump from a production server every hour as a backup. When we try to restore from the dumps some of the dumps restore successfully and some fails with the above error. If a dump throws error while restoring first time it continuously throws error every time we try to restore it.

Comment: OK, then can we have a look at lines 1640-1655 of the dump file that reliably and repeatably throws an error at line 1647?  It's only the line that throws the error, and a few lines either side, that are of interest; not the whole file.  Also, how are you getting the file from the prod server to the box where the restore is done?

Comment: Previously we copied the dump from the production server to our local server but the restore was not successful. We have a replication running in our local environment and now if I take dump from the replication server also the same error occurs. The escape character in the quote is not always same for every dump and also the line number. How you want me to update the data here ?

Comment: Ummm, click the "edit" link under the question?  And "copied" is all very well, I guessed that - but **how** did you copy it?  ftp? scp? nfs? rsync-over-ssh?  rsync-over-rsync-server?  samba share?

Comment: @MadHatter I think pasting the line would be problematic here since the size of 1 single row is 1MB.

I use scp normally to copy dumps from production server. Now, after some experimentation I am able to find a clue. There is a table called "ib_mail_sent" which contains dump of all mails. Every time when I get the error it points to a row with a insert query to "ib_mail_sent" but there are few same kind of insert queries before and after this query. My assumption is while importing MySQL might be running out of buffer. Can you please suggest if there is any such buffer involved ?

Comment: @MadHatter adding --hex-blob while taking the dump solved the issue.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have binary data use the mysqldump parameter --hex-blob.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the --skip-extended-insert of mysqldump, that makes it use a new line for each insert and that can solve the problem particularly if you are editing the dump file.